# MS Outlook autocorrect (Office 365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, autocorrect

I'm using Outlook on Windows 10 and Office 365 for Small business. My default language is Slovenian (SI).

When I start writing a new message the default language is SI and when I write in English everything is underlined in red. This is expected.

But there is a strange autocorrect setting that I just cannot find where to fix. Whenever I write `for the` it automatically gets corrected to `fort he`.

I have checked all the settings in *Options-Mail-Editor*, but I cannot find the one that is causing this behaviour.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add an entry to the autocorrect list that replaces “for the” with “for the”. This way, you can override the default autocorrection that changes “for the” to “fort he”.
To add an entry to the autocorrect list:

- Go to File > Options > Mail and select Editor Options.
- Select Proofing > AutoCorrect Options.
- On the AutoCorrect tab, type “for the” in the Replace box and “for the” in the With box.
- Click Add.

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-or-remove-autocorrect-entries-in-outlook-90061862-d6eb-45a9-8bfd-81ac592bb59b

Comment: Seems to work. Thank you. Still, why was it replaced in the the first place (the word "fort" does not exist in my language)...